# How to upgrade Hibernate from version 4.3 to 5.2 for migration to JDK 10?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-5.x, java-10

Since `JDK8 Oracle` announced that no longer support, I am required to upgrade the current `JDK` to `JDK10`.

After study, the current `hibernate` is also required to upgrade from `hibernate 4` to `hibernate 5`, in order to run at `JDK 10.`

However, there are some hibernate related libraries, should I also upgrade, if yes, which version that is suitable? Here is an extract of my current `pom.xml`:

```
<properties>
<hibernate.version>4.3.11.Final</hibernate.version>
<java-version>1.7</java-version>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<!-- hibernate -->
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>  
     <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
     <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
     <version>5.1.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 11):

Speaking merely about dependencies, the upgrade from Hibernate *4.3.x* to *>= 5.2.x* is pretty straight forward. The latest >= [5.2.x](http://hibernate.org/orm/releases/5.2/) version is pretty solid and has been tested by the community for quite some time now. The more recent versions >= [5.3.x](http://hibernate.org/orm/releases/5.3/) have been released in November 2020.

You can achieve the migration in your `pom.xml` with the following snippets:

### Hibernate 5.2.x

```
<properties>
    <hibernate.version>5.2.18.Final</hibernate.version>
    <hibernate.validator.version>6.0.21.Final</hibernate.validator.version>

    <java-version>10</java-version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<!-- hibernate -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.validator.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

### Hibernate 5.3.x

Just replace one property value to read:

```
<hibernate.version>5.3.22.Final</hibernate.version>
```

All other relevant transitive dependencies are pulled in via the above artifacts automatically.

***Note well***

The `hibernate-entitymanager-...jar` which was used by your original `pom.xml` snippet no longer exists in Hibernate 5.2.x. Everything which is related to JPA/EntityManager is now incorporated in `hibernate-core-...jar`.

### Hibernate Validator

Starting with the release of version **6.0.10**, the library fully supports JDK10:

> You can now build and use Hibernate Validator with JDK 10.

For reference see: http://in.relation.to/2018/05/15/hibernate-validator-6010-final-out/

### Checks...

Moreover, review every `persistence.xml` file in the project so that

1. you set: `<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>`
2. and define the header to be JPA **2.1** compliant:

   ```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
         version="2.1">
   ```

**or**
3. to be JPA **2.2** compliant as

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
     <persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd"
         version="2.2">
```

### Further remarks

In theory, all important dependencies should be drawn into your project with the above snippets. However, in practice, you will (most likely) encounter some breaking changes at *compile* or *runtime* with your existing project code. Many of these can be resolved by checking the official migration guides here:

- Version *4.3.x -> 5.0.x*:

  https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.0/migration-guide.adoc is a MUCH recommend read in your case (since you start at version 4.3.x)
- Version *5.0.x -> 5.1.x*:

  http://staging.hibernate.org/orm/documentation/5.1/migration/
  can be skipped except you make use of BLOBs and Oracle's DBMS or use Hibernate's schema export tools
- Version *5.1.x -> 5.2.x*:

  https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/wiki/Migration-Guide---5.2
  contains a lot of information on important changes, such as PK generation, LimitHandler and others
- Version *5.2.x -> 5.3.x*:

  https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/wiki/Migration-Guide---5.3 which adds full JPA 2.2 support and should work fine in JDK8/9/10 environments.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I got this error after I upgrade from 4.3 to 5.3 could you help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64688273/hibernate-subclass-has-to-be-binded-after-its-mother-class