# Is Hibernate 4 compatible with Java 11?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, java-11, hibernate-4.x

I have already read on documents saying that Hibernate version 5 is compatible with Java 11. but

- Is Hibernate ORM version 4 also compatible with Java 11?
- if not: What changes are required to upgrade?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hibernate 4 is **not** compatible with Java 11 and was declared, for quite some years now, as ”*[end-of-life](https://hibernate.org/orm/releases/4.3/)*“, practically since end of 2015.

Full Java 11 support was [announced](https://hibernate.org/orm/releases/5.4/) with Hibernate version **5.4**:

> Hibernate ORM now supports JDK 11 out of the box.

[Hibernate *5.3*](https://hibernate.org/orm/releases/5.3/) lists Java 11 as supported in the latest release 5.3.22. Moreover, [Hibernate *5.6*](https://hibernate.org/orm/releases/5.6/)  is also Java 11 compatible. This might be the last version in the `javax` namespace, yet it supports the transition to the new `jakarta` namespace.

Pointers on what changed or needs changes in your project are found via this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50909365) or in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50748341/2849346) to a similar question, related to migration from version 4.3 to version 5.2. Many things in that answer should guide you along the path.