# Migrating to hibernate 5.1.16 from hibernate 4.3 have QuerySyntaxException

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, migration, hibernate-5.x

I'm trying to migrate my `hibernate 4.3` to `hibernate 5.1.16` and I am ending up with `QuerySyntaxException` which am not able to figure after one week.

I am using annotation for mapping and I checked my queries all of those uses the same name of my entity class, there is no conflict in the name in my queries which am sure and also the point is it worked with `Hibernate 4.3`.

All the solution in the web is only pointing to naming **`conflicts.__Maintence`** is my first table and the mapping issue is pointing at this table.

Here is my **`hibernate.cfg`** which I use for mapping.

```
<mapping class="wadetech.DB.entity.__Maintenance"/>
```

This is **`my __Maintenance`** class

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "__maintenance", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "name"))
public class __Maintenance implements java.io.Serializable {
```

This is **`my __MaintenanceDAO`**

```java
public Collection<__Maintenance> getMaintenanceByName(String name){
    String query = "";
    query += "select m from __Maintenance m";
    query += "  where m.name = :name ";
    query += " order by ";
    query += "   m.startDate desc, m.idMaintenance desc";
    return super.list(query, "name", name);
}
```

And here is my **exception**

```
 wadetech.exceptions.InfrastructureException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: __Maintenance is not mapped [select m from __Maintenance m  where m.name = :name  order by    m.startDate desc, m.idMaintenance desc]
    at wadetech.DB.base.BaseDAO.anonymousFindByQuery(BaseDAO.java:267)
    at wadetech.DB.base.BaseDAO.findByQuery(BaseDAO.java:255)
    at wadetech.DB.base.BaseDAO.list(BaseDAO.java:243)
    at wadetech.DB.DAOS.__MaintenanceDAO.getMaintenanceByName(__MaintenanceDAO.java:78)
    at com.at.project.utils.runtime.RuntimeModifier.HasExecuted(RuntimeModifier.java:128)
    at wadetech.listeners.ModificationScriptStartupListener.contextInitialized(ModificationScriptStartupListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5528)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: __Maintenance is not mapped [select m from __Maintenance m  where m.name = :name  order by    m.startDate desc, m.idMaintenance desc]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:76)
```

Am also adding a section of my `HibernateUtil` as I have my doubts this is causing due to some transaction issues which I changed after moving to `5.1`
Before I used `tx.wasCommitted();`

which I can't use anymore as was Committed is omitted in `hibernate 5.1` so I changed it to the below code `tx.getStatus() == TransactionStatus.COMMITTED`

Here is my **hibernateUtil**

```java
public static void beginTransaction(boolean readOnly) throws InfrastructureException {

    try {
        if( currentConnectionMode == ConnectionMode.MASTER_SLAVE && readOnly ) {
            // it is a readOnly tx
            Transaction tx = readOnlyThreadTransaction.get();
            if (null == tx || tx.getStatus() == TransactionStatus.COMMITTED || tx.getStatus() == TransactionStatus.ROLLED_BACK) {
                tx = getReadOnlySession().beginTransaction();
                readOnlyThreadTransaction.set(tx);
            }
        } else {
            Transaction tx = threadTransaction.get();
            if (null == tx || tx.getStatus() == TransactionStatus.COMMITTED || tx.getStatus() == TransactionStatus.ROLLED_BACK) {
                tx = getSession().beginTransaction();
                threadTransaction.set(tx);
            }
        } // end if
    } // end try
    catch (HibernateException ex) {
        WLog.DAOLogger.error("Begin transaction", ex);
        throw new InfrastructureException(ex);
    } // end catch
}
```

I want to stick on with *hibernate 5.1* and don't want to migrate to *hibernate 5.2* as 5.2 uses jdk 8+. I prefer hibernate 5.1 because I strictly need to use jdk 1.7

Comment: @Dushyant Tankariya Do you have any idea about my post.It will be helpful thanks.

Comment: Not sure, but you can have a look at [one of the StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50207195/how-to-upgrade-hibernate-from-version-4-3-to-5-2-for-migration-to-jdk-10)

Comment: I want to stick with jdk 1.7 that's why I choose hibernate 5.1 as all the above versions of hibernate 5.1.16 use jdk 1.8. I have only  this mapping issue which I am looking to sort out. Thanks

Comment: Else you can go through the [github migration-guide](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.0/migration-guide.adoc) which may help you somehow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upgrade Hibernate from version 4.3 to 5.2 for migration to JDK 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50207195/how-to-upgrade-hibernate-from-version-4-3-to-5-2-for-migration-to-jdk-10)

Comment: @Sterconium Thank you for your response.But Its not. I am using hibernate **5.1 **which still use ** jdk 1.7**. So  I don't want to migrate my jdk.

Comment: Then you should edit your question to specify you want to keep the same jdk

Comment: @Sterconium Do so,Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So finally I solve the above issue was.Even though the exception din't help to point the issue. The real problem was at hibernateUtils.
Before this was how  my hiberenate utils  for hibernate 4.3.

```
serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
                        configuration.getProperties()).build();
                sessionFactory = configuration.configure().buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

and I changed it to

```
registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build();
                 MetadataSources sources = new MetadataSources(registry);
                 Metadata metadata = sources.getMetadataBuilder().build();
                 sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
```